# How do I shift a set of lines one space to the right within a text editor?

Tags: visual-studio, editor

How do I shift a set of lines one space to the right within a text editor?

If I wanted to shift a set of lines several spaces to the right, I would perform:

```
selected text + Tab
```

However, I just want to shift the text one space to the right without tabbing.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Hold down the alt key, left-click *and hold the mouse button down* on the first line where you wish to insert your space. Then, while still holding down the left mouse button, drag the mouse vertically to extend this edit point to all the lines you want to move.  Dragging it horizontally will create a box selection, which you want to avoid, as the selected text will end up being replaced, rather than a space be added.

Also, you cannot select individual, disjoint lines to move.  You can only use alt-drag over a contiguous block of lines.

Once you have your multiline edit point created, hit the spacebar once.

Tada.

[Here's a blog post by Scott Guthrie with more details and a vidya demo](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/box-selection-and-multi-line-editing-with-vs-2010)

**If you don't want to use the mouse,** you can use <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>(up, down, left, or right)</kbd> to create a box selection, or a multiline edit point.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using a mouse (i.e. keyboard only)?

Comment: Yes, you can use [shift] + [alt] + [up]/[down] to just "enlarge the cursor up or down (same as with [alt]+mouse and then press [space] one or more times to add space at the cursor position for all "cursored" lines

Comment: So far both methods (mouse and keyboard) actually work in Notepad++ and VisualStudio Code.